# hibernate query to check single value with list property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes.

```
1.Course.java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id; 
private String name;



2.Student.java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id; 
private String name;
@ManyToMany
private List<Course> course;
```

Now i need a list of student where course id = 1 or course id is null;
query like "FROM Student st WHERE st.course = 1 or course id is null".
How to write this query in hql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join:

```
select s from Student s inner join s.courses c where c.id = 1
```

Note that I chose to rename the fields `course` to `courses` in this query: a student has many courses, and the final **s** makes that clear.

Comment: how can i check with null

Comment: Check what with null?

Comment: check if no course. because course is not essential in this case.

Comment: A query doesn't check anything. It selects things. What would you like the query to select? Your question asked how to get all the students having the course 1. So what would you like it to actually do?

Comment: sorry to unclear it. the query like 'select s from Student s inner join s.courses c where c.id = 1 or c.id is null'. if i check course id with null it showing exception.